# balance loading in Sharepoint wfe

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, load-balancing

Can somebody give information about load balancing and how to configure in wfe. My wfe will have multiple web applications and multiple site collections. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can check following links for load balancing in sharpoint:

http://www.loadbalancer.org/sharepoint.php

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/2d7fc33a-81ca-4f8e-9876-a75706917b2e/sharepoint-2013-web-frontend-url-load-balancing

Comment: Hi  thanks for the info. So this will work for sp foundation2010 as well right. Because in the document it is mentioned about sp server2010. So ,

Comment: Yes it would work for sharepoint foundation. As i don't see any difference in load balancing for sharepoint server and sharepoint foundation